# Unhashing a hashed (MD5) email address

Tags: python, hash, md5

I know that in hashing you, by definition, lose information. However, as email addresses can be restricted - such as with the information available I would know a potential domain of the email, and that it must have an @. Do these constraints change anything about the problem? Or is the best way to simply make a guess and see if the hash is the same? Also MD5 is no longer as secure as it once was.

Thanks

Comment: `MD5 is no longer as secure as it once was.` worse - MD5 was deprecated 11 years ago. A 2009 GPU [could calculate 200 million hashes per second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security). You can easily brute force this in 2022, calculating email combinations until you find a match. Don't even think about using MD5 for anything sensitive

Comment: Even in 2009 though, sensitive data like passwords was salted and hashed *multiple* times - at least 1000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the point of Md5 hashing that even a minute change in the string can change the hash completely. So these constraints change nothing about the problem.

However since you said that its an email and that you know about the potential domain then you can try this technique.

1. Generate a list of potential emails it will be within 26 letters and lets say of maximum size 10.

Then you can generate an md5 for all of these possibilities and check if it is equal to the one you have.

```
import hashlib
from itertools import combinations
import time

start=time.time()
your_md5_hash='your_md5_hash'
letters='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
possible_words=[]
for r in range(1,10): #change 10 to the maximum size of your email
    for combo in combinations(list(letters), r=r):
        res=''.join(combo)
        possible_words.append(res)


possible_words=[''.join(x)+'@domain.com' for x in possible_words]
print (len(possible_words))
for x in possible_words:
    res=hashlib.md5(x.encode())
    if res==your_md5_hash:
        print (res)
        print (x)
        print ("RESULT_FOUND")
        exit(0)

print (time.time()-start)
```

This is brute force approach and if you know the size of your email then this could work. Secondly please note that if you do not know the size then the size of possibilities will increase exponentially.

For instance the length of combinations as of now is 5658536 and it took my basic laptop 6 seconds to process.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning explicitly: if you really do plan to brute force this, you'll want to use GPUs, and lots of them. A single python interpreter will spin on this forever, more or less.

Comment: @Alexander not with MD5. The reason it's not used is that modern machines are so fast they can brute-force MD5 calculations. [A 2009 GPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security) could calculate 200M hashes per second.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You said it yourself: a 2009 ***GPU***

Comment: On my pc 26 letters with total combinations of 5658536 it took 6 seconds to process. 
Now if there are Capital letters also in it and there are lets say 5 special characters it makes total size to 10954161067 that means it will take around 193 minutes to run it (calculated w.r.t current size) (didnt run it). Which seems like a feasible time and that is on my pc. I have not ran it but the op can easily save the possibilities in a parquet file and run it.

Comment: @ibadia email addresses aren't case sensitive though. Common additional characters would be numbers, dots, dashes but that's still less than 26. On top of that, hashlib is slow and your code is single threaded. Using a library that takes advantage of SIMD operations, parallelizing the loop, could result in far better performance